# Fade coin in and out javascript canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I have a coin image `coin.png` I would like to appear and then fade up torwards the top of the canvas and then disappear but should be able to continuosly spawn randomly with the same behavior but im not sure how to do this with my current set up for example I am using my canvas in this manner

```js
function writeMessage(canvas, message,x,y) {
        var terminal = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ClearCanvas();
        terminal.font = "20px Comic Sans MS";
        terminal.fillStyle = "rgb(0,255,1)";
        terminal.textAlign = "center";
        terminal.fillText(message, x, y);
}
function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
        x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
        y: evt.clientY - rect.top
    };
}

var canvas = document.getElementById("terminalCanvas");
var terminal = canvas.getContext("2d");

terminal.fillStyle = "#000000";
terminal.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
terminal.font = "20px Comic Sans MS";
terminal.fillStyle = "rgb(0,255,1)";
terminal.textAlign = "center";
terminal.fillText("Coding Idle Terminal", canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2);

$('#terminalCanvas').click(function(evt){
    WriteToCanvas();
    function WriteToCanvas(){
        if(Game.Terminal.HTMLSupport == 1 && Game.Terminal.CSSSupport == 0){ 
            var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 122) + 1;
            var tag = htmltags[rand];

            Game.Player.money += Game.Player.clickIncrement + (Game.Player.clickIncrement * Game.Player.codingGods/100);
            Game.Player.exp += Game.Player.clickIncrement + (Game.Player.clickIncrement * Game.Player.codingGods/100);
            Game.Player.clicksTotal += Game.Player.clickIncrement + + (Game.Player.clickIncrement * Game.Player.codingGods/100);

            var mousePos = getMousePos(canvas,evt);
            var message = tag;
            writeMessage(canvas, message,mousePos.x,mousePos.y);

        }else if(Game.Terminal.CSSSupport == 1 && Game.Terminal.JavascriptSupport == 0){
            var tagList = htmltags.concat(csstags);
            var tagListLength = tagList.length;
            var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * tagListLength) + 1;
            var tagg = tagList[rand];

            Game.Player.money += Game.Player.clickIncrement + (Game.Player.clickIncrement * Game.Player.codingGods/100);
            Game.Player.exp += Game.Player.clickIncrement + (Game.Player.clickIncrement * Game.Player.codingGods/100);
            Game.Player.clicksTotal += Game.Player.clickIncrement + + (Game.Player.clickIncrement * Game.Player.codingGods/100);

            var mousePos = getMousePos(canvas,evt);
            var message = tagg;
            writeMessage(canvas, message,mousePos.x,mousePos.y);
        }else if(Game.Terminal.JavascriptSupport == 1 && Game.Terminal.PHPSupport == 0){
            var t1 = csstags.concat(javascripttags);
            var tagList = htmltags.concat(t1);
            var tagListLength = tagList.length;
            var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * tagListLength) + 1;
            var tagg = tagList[rand];

            Game.Player.money += Game.Player.clickIncrement + (Game.Player.clickIncrement * Game.Player.codingGods/100);
            Game.Player.exp += Game.Player.clickIncrement + (Game.Player.clickIncrement * Game.Player.codingGods/100);
            Game.Player.clicksTotal += Game.Player.clickIncrement + + (Game.Player.clickIncrement * Game.Player.codingGods/100);

            var mousePos = getMousePos(canvas,evt);
            var message = tagg;
            writeMessage(canvas, message,mousePos.x,mousePos.y);
        }else if(Game.Terminal.PHPSupport == 1){
            var t1 = csstags.concat(javascripttags);
            var t2 = t1.concat(t1);
            var tagList = htmltags.concat(t2);
            var tagListLength = tagList.length;
            var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * tagListLength) + 1;
            var tagg = tagList[rand];

            Game.Player.money += Game.Player.clickIncrement + (Game.Player.clickIncrement * Game.Player.codingGods/100);
            Game.Player.exp += Game.Player.clickIncrement + (Game.Player.clickIncrement * Game.Player.codingGods/100);
            Game.Player.clicksTotal += Game.Player.clickIncrement + + (Game.Player.clickIncrement * Game.Player.codingGods/100);

            var mousePos = getMousePos(canvas,evt);
            var message = tagg;
            writeMessage(canvas, message,mousePos.x,mousePos.y);
        }
    }
});

function ClearCanvas(){
    terminal.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    terminal.fillStyle = "#000000";
    terminal.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
}
```

Now I would much prefer to have a seperate function I can call perhaps

```js
function coinRandom(){
  var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;

  if(number == 56){
    //Draw coin to screen and other stuff

    Game.Player.relics += 1;
  }else{
    //Do nothing
  }
}
```

The biggest part of the function is it should get the mousePos.x and mousePos.y and draw the coin there and then from there fade out torwards the top of the canvas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to establish a list of coins that are moving on the screen. The coins will need to be animated during each frame of the game. The function you desire will then add coins to the list at the appropriate time. You will need a second function that is called during each frame of the game that will check the list of coins, then animate and draw a coin for each entry in the list.

Here is a fiddle that uses random numbers to put the coin on the screen:

https://jsfiddle.net/05t6v8sL/

```
var rW = 400;
var rH = 500;

var coinImage = getCoinImage();
var coinsOnScreen = [];
var maxCoins = 50;
var risingSpeed = 200; //pixels per second...

var lastAnimationTime = 0;

function doDraw() {
    var can = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  can.width = rW;
  can.height = rH;
  var context = can.getContext("2d");

  //Erase the canvas
  context.fillStyle="#FFFFFF";
  context.fillRect(0, 0, rW, rH);

    //if there are less than maxCoins on the screen, add a new coin to a random position:
   if (coinsOnScreen.length<maxCoins) {
    //generate random x and y coordinates:
    var newX = Math.floor(Math.random() * rW) + 1;
    var newY = Math.floor(Math.random() * rH) + 1;

    var newCoin = {
        x: newX,
      y: newY,
      stl: 4
    };
    coinsOnScreen.push(newCoin);
   }

   //Now draw the coins
   if (lastAnimationTime != 0) {

    var deltaTime = new Date().getTime() - lastAnimationTime;
    var coinRisePixels = Math.floor((deltaTime * risingSpeed)/1000);

    var survivingCoins = [];
    for (var i=0;i<coinsOnScreen.length;i++) {
        var coin = coinsOnScreen[i];
      coin.y = coin.y - coinRisePixels;
      //the stl variable controlls the alpha of the image
      coin.stl = (coin.stl * 1000 - deltaTime)/1000;            
      if (coin.y+50 > 0) {
      var alpha = coin.stl/6;      
        context.save();
        context.globalAlpha=alpha;        
        context.drawImage(coinImage, coin.x, coin.y);
        context.restore();
        //this coin is still on the screen, so promote it to the new array...
        survivingCoins.push(coin);
      }
    }
    coinsOnScreen = survivingCoins;
   }   
  lastAnimationTime = new Date().getTime();  
  //Wait, and then call this function again to animate:
  setTimeout(function() {
    doDraw();
  }, 30);   
}

doDraw();

function getCoinImage() {
var image = new Image(50, 50);
image.src="data:image/png;base64,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";
return image;
}
```

When each frame is drawn, the code will add a new coin to the coinsOnScreen array unless maxCoins count has been reached.

The number of pixels the coin will rise depends on the deltaTime of the frame rate. The pixels are subtracted from each coin in each frame until the coin is off the screen, at this point, the coin should be removed from the screen.

The alpha value of the coin is controlled by the "stl" variable that is assigned to each coin.

The effect you describe reminds me of when Mario grabs a coin and it briefly flies in the air. If this is more of the effect you desire, then instead of simply subtracting pixels from the y coordinate of the coin, you would calculate its path along a projectile function, like a parabola.